# UITableViewController subclass won't load

Tags: uitableview, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to show in the screen a table...

Basically I create a custom UITableViewController with the methods needed for the UITableView delegate and data source which is self since UITableViewController does it for you.

When I put it in the `-initWithRootView:` controller, and add the nav's bar view to the window it doesn't show! With debugging, the table is being created and all, but the delegate methods are never called!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually calling -reloadData on the table memory of your controller? This will, if everything's hooked up, call your delegate/datasource methods. If that doesn't do anything, (a) something's not hooked up right, or (b) you're not loading your controller properly.

Answer (score 0):

I created the table and added the tableView property directly to the window instead and it worked. I don't think adding reloaddata would make it work since this controller does it automatically. Something is not correct when adding it as a rootviewcontroller to the navigation bar controller probably!